# Indexing nested list by a list

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, indexing, nested-lists

given a nested list like

```
>>> m= [[3, 1], [2, 7]]
```

I can get an element like this

```
>>> m[1][0]
2
```

How can i get the same value if the index is given in a list, i.e. as `[1, 0]`?

I am looking for something that the Q programming language offers with [dot](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/6_Functions/#682-verb-dot) like in code below

```
q) m: (3 1; 2 7)
q) m[1][0]
2
q) m . 1 0
2
```

Comment: You can define a class with a `get` method that takes `[1, 0]` as a parameter. This solution has been used in `pandas` for example. `accessor = MyAccessor([[3, 1], [2, 7]]); accessor.get([1,0])`

Answer (score 5):

As a quick-n-dirty solution, you can *abuse* `functools.reduce` like this:

```
from functools import reduce
def get_recursive(lst, idx_list):
    return reduce(list.__getitem__, [lst, *idx_list])
```

```
>>> y = [[3, 1], [2, 7]]
>>> get_recursive(y, [0, 1])
1
>>> get_recursive(y, [1, 0])
2
```

There are quite a few corner cases to handle (plus you'd have to be sure the path exists or else handle any errors that arise) but this should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

just define a recursive function that takes the index of the passed list, then passes this index and the sliced index list to itself, until the sliced index list is empty:

```
def get(m,l):
    if not l:
        return m
    return get(m[l[0]],l[1:])

print(get([[3, 1], [2, 7]],[1,0]))
```

prints: `2`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to NumPy array first:

```
import numpy as np

m = [[3, 1], [2, 7]]
np.array(m)[1,0]
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: Not really. Perhaps OP does not want to install and use numpy just for this. Perhaps the list is ragged, etc. The solution isn't as simple as you thought, is it? (In response to your original post before it was edited)

Comment: Well the OP never mentioned anything about using/not using numpy. This numpy argument can be used in general to majority of answers/comments for python tags. I assumed  that the index actually refers to an element. I don't see why you downvoted. Anyway, it's your opinion. I was just giving a relatively simpler solution as compared to the others.

Comment: It can, but that usually doesn't mean it is appropriate to do so. And why did you assume I downvoted your post?

Comment: What would be the syntax if `l= [1, 0]`

Comment: The answer is for `l=[1,0]`. What do you mean?

Comment: If `l= [1,0]` then how can you index your numpy array with `l`? For example `np.array(m) l` does not work.

Comment: @Ferenc Indexing and list literals both use square brackets, but they're different things.

Answer (score 1):

This solution requires imports, but only from the standard library. Very similar to [@cs95's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51575197/4518341), but slightly cleaner in my view.

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import getitem

nested_list = [[[['test'], ['test1']], ['test2']], ['test3', 'test4']]
indices = [0, 1, 0]

assert reduce(getitem, indices, nested_list) == 'test2'
```