# Reference an item in a nested list with a list of indexes

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have an arbitrarily nested list in Python and I want to modify an item in that list. For that I'd like to use a list of indexes. It would be similar to traditional way of indexing nested lists `list[0][2][1]` but I'd like to have these same indexes stored in a list like `[0, 2, 1]`

For example a piece of pseudo-code of how it would work:

```
nestedList = [[0,1],[2,3]]
indexList = [1, 0]
replacement = 6
nestedList = ReplaceItemInNestedList(nestedList, indexList, replacement)

nestedList: [[0,1],[6,3]]
```

This far I have managed to only create a way of accessing an item, but not modifying it. The code for that would be following.

```
for i in indexList:
    nestedList = nestedList[i]
# nestedList will equal to item when loop has finished.
```

There surely is a way to modify an item as accessing one is so simple, but I can't find a way how. Two years ago there was pretty much the same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51575090/indexing-nested-list-by-a-list) but answers required importing libraries. Is it possible without importing libraries?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, yes, all you have to do is iterate over all the indexes, *except* the last one and use that to perform the replacement:

```py
def ReplaceItemInNestedList(nestedList, indexList, replacement):
    for i in indexList[:-1]:
        nestedList = nestedList[i]
    lastIndex = indexList[-1]
    nestedList[lastIndex] = replacement
    
nestedList = [[0,1],[2,3]]
indexList = [1, 0]
replacement = 6
ReplaceItemInNestedList(nestedList, indexList, replacement)
print(nestedList)
```

Output as requested

Answer (score 1):

Your last item in `indexList` is the index of the item in the innermost list. So you need to have the final list by traversing upto the second last element in the `indexlist`. For this, do:

```
finalList = nestedList
for index in indexList[:-1]:
    finalList = finalList[index]
finalList[indexList[-1]] = replacement
```